# How Can I Compare Audio File Of Different Bit-rates Having The Same Audio Content in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio

(PS:- As The Bit-rates Are different The Check-sums Will Obviously Be Different And Names & ID3 Tags  Cannot Be Taken Into Consideration Due To Various WEB-Hosting Customizations)
I Have tried matching (using MIR-TOOLBOX IN MATLAB) The /Spectrum /Flux /Envelope /Histogram /etc But The Readings Differ Variably !

Comment: If these files are ID3 tagged, your best option is to write some code to handle the webserver's customisations. This will almost certainly be easier than trying to match them statistically, which is really opening a Pandora's box...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simple problem - you will not be able to make an exact comparison.  My recommendation is that you down-sample the higher bit-rate version, then perform the comparison.  Have a look at [downsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling) on Wikipedia and go from there.

Comment: THis Is Not Possible For large Databases!